# WinRT Universal App: Bottom bar icons blurred.

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, blur

I have used 76*76 png file for bottom bar icon in my windows universal app.

Below is my xaml for mobile bottom bar

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar RequestedTheme="Dark" Background="#FFF3A716">
        <AppBarButton x:Uid="AppBarHome" Click="AppBarButton_Click">
            <AppBarButton.Icon>
                <BitmapIcon HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"   UriSource="/Assets/Images/home-icon.png">

                </BitmapIcon>
            </AppBarButton.Icon>
        </AppBarButton>

    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

And this is my bottom bar for tablet app:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar  Name="BtmBar" Closed="CommandBar_Closed" RequestedTheme="Dark" Background="#FFF3A716" IsOpen="True" IsSticky="True">
        <AppBarButton x:Uid="AppBarHome" Click="AppBarButton_Click">
            <AppBarButton.Icon>
                <BitmapIcon HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"   UriSource="/Assets/Images/home-icon2.png">

                </BitmapIcon>
            </AppBarButton.Icon>
        </AppBarButton>

    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

home-icon is 76*76 and home-icon2 is 96*96.
I have tried 76*76 icon for both also but in phone it seems ok and in tablet it is blurred.

How can I get rid of this blurry issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make more than one scale and let Windows -auto- choose the perfect one .. This image may help you : https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2yGW.jpg .

Ref: [AppBar button icon not fitting inside elipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28935766/appbar-button-icon-not-fitting-inside-elipse)

Scaling Ref : [How to create multi scaled image assets for a WP 8.1 Store app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27055226/how-to-create-multi-scaled-image-assets-for-a-wp-8-1-store-app)